# Comparing strings that contain accents in SQLite for Java doesn't work

Tags: java, string, encoding, sqlite

I'm reading some bowling players' names in a file and then I need to find those names in a SQLite database to calculate their average.

Everything works perfectly, except for names that contain accents (such as "É").

I've used `PRAGMA Encoding` in SQLite Manager and the database is encoded in UTF-8. I also made sure that my Java uses UTF-8 for encoding by outputting `Charset.defaultCharset();`

Also, if I run my query in SQLite Manager, everything works great, which actually makes me pretty sure that there's something I need to do with the JDBC SQLite driver. I haven't found a way to see or change which encoding it uses. I'm not even sure that's the problem at all.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public double getPlayerAverage(String name, String leagueName){
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    double average = 0.0;

    try{
        connect();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT AVG(Score)Average FROM Scores " +
                " JOIN Players p1 USING (PlayerID) " +
                " WHERE UPPER(Name) = ? AND UPPER(LeagueName) = ? AND Season = '2012-2013' AND Score > -1" +
                " GROUP BY Season, LeagueName, PlayerID; ");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, leagueName);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            average = rs.getDouble("Average");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(name + " --- " + leagueName);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        closer(rs, ps);
    }

    return average;
}
```

The "else" outputs the names that don't have an associated average, which means that those players haven't been found in the database. All the names outputted this way contain accents and no names containing accents are parsed successfully.

Comment: Which Sqlite driver for Java are you using?

Comment: @Thilo I'm using sqlitejdbc-v056

Comment: Maybe you can try another one? Like this one (which I understand wraps the native library if possible): https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. I just tried but I have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPPER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#upper) handles only ASCII characters.

You should ensure that player names have consistent capitalization when searching them.
(Your code already assumes that spelling, name order, initials etc. are consistent.)

(And what happens when two players have the same name?)

Comment: +1. The UPPER should go. But this does not explain why it works in SQLite Manager. And UPPER may not upper-case accented characters, but it might still work (somewhat) if it just keeps them as is (which it should)

Comment: A working query would be something like `WHERE UPPER(Name) = 'SOMé NAMé'`.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. But like Thilo said, it's stange that the same query works in SQLite Manager